# Spring webflow serialization trouble in production

Tags: spring, grails, spring-webflow

I have a grails app doing some stuff in the right way with webflow. So everything goes right in development mode, i can finish the registration and objects are serialized normally. But then, in production mode, deployed on a tomcat 7 with ssl, the following error appears when it's time to persist datas. In a nutshell the serialization don't work. Please help, i have no idea at the moment.
The only difference of configuration is that i force https with spring security in production.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat7/stacktrace.log
-------------------------------------
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1018)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1018)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1443)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1414)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:960)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1443)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1414)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:186)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
2013-05-15 22:59:30,262 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:186)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.webflow.engine.builder.ActionDelegate
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1018)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1018)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:438)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1443)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1414)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:960)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:959)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1443)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1414)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Full stack trace updated.

Comment: Nothing after "5 more"? It seems that the root cause is not present in the stacktrace.

Comment: Can you provide the code where objects are inserted to the HashMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It looks like the problem could be related to [the following JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBFLOW-16)  issue.

Please try the workaround mentioned in the issue comments.

---

If your command/domain object used in your form doesn't implement serializable such an error will be displayed.

Make sure that **ALL** objects(domain, commands, model objects) **involved in the flow scope** (your wizard with webflow) implement serializable.

Comment: All objects are implementing serializable, the app works well in dev mode as it's specified in the topic

Comment: The pb was related to the cluster mode in prod: webflow needs the hibernate session name to serialize objects between tomcat cells. Weird and undocumented:  <hibernate-configuration>

 <session-factory name="sessionFactory">

Comment: before finding this stuff, i made transient all the beforeInsert() , it didn't change the error for my app, but it's better like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <hibernate-configuration> <session-factory name="sessionFactory">
```

There is an open  jira ticket for that: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBFLOW-85

Comment: You should accept your own answer in this case. Also it would have been difficult to guess that you were using some Hibernate mappings from your question. If you had provided that USEFUL information in your question, it could have been easier to find out what was wrong.