# Spring-webflow SnapshotCreationException Error after login

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-webflow

I am working with a java project with spring-webflow and Primefaces 3.3
The version of Primefaces cannot be increased due to menu developments and other components that generate an error when trying to upgrade the version. The problem is not this.

The problem comes from setting the max-execution-snapshots property. If I put a value other than 0, it generates the exception indicated by the statement.

I thought that it could be some objects that weren't serializable, but I have implemented serialization and it continues with the same result.
Before refactoring the project, passing it from ant build to Maven, it was not necessary to indicate in the flow-executor the flow-execution-repository. The most curious thing is that they are the same libraries that are used:
spring-faces-2.4.1.RELEASE, spring-webflow-2.4.1.RELEASE and the rest of spring are 4.3.16.RELEASE.

When the application loads, it makes a call to return a list, but this is not the fault. I guess the problem must be in the call to the WebService because the error it throws in the root cause is: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy

I don't know if it's also a problem with the filters, I don't know exactly. I have been looking for a solution for several days, but I didn't succeed.

I put here the stack trace and the spring-webflow configuration
Thanks in advance!

**spring-webflow.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
   xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd">

    <faces:resources/>

    <!-- Spring Webflow central configuration component -->
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
        <webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="10" max-execution-snapshots="-1"/>
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>          
            <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>          
            <webflow:listener ref="securityListener"/>
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>
    
    <!-- Installs a listener that creates and releases the FacesContext for each request. -->   
    <bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>   
    
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" 
        base-path="/WEB-INF/flows/" >
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location id="parent-flow" path="parent-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>
    
    <!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration --> 
    <faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices" development="true" />
    
    <bean id="mvcViewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="viewResolver"/>
            </list>
        </property>     
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
          <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>
          
    <!-- Dispatches requests mapped to flows to FlowHandler implementations --> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">      
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" /> 
    </bean>
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

*The filters shown in the stacktrace are from third parties, we don't have the code*

**StackTrace**

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable


JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report

JBWEB000068: message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    com.jeveris.web.core.filter.log.PerformanceLogFilter.doFilter(PerformanceLogFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.axa.ca.caem.credentials.IamAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(IamAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)



JBWEB000071: root cause 
org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SnapshotCreationException: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.<init>(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:75)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.createSnapshot(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:70)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.snapshot(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:75)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.putFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:126)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:145)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:238)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    com.jeveris.web.core.filter.log.PerformanceLogFilter.doFilter(PerformanceLogFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.axa.ca.caem.credentials.IamAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(IamAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)



JBWEB000071: root cause 
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
    java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalAttributeMap.writeObject(LocalAttributeMap.java:333)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowSessionImpl.writeExternal(FlowSessionImpl.java:162)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1131)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.writeExternal(FlowExecutionImpl.java:311)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.serialize(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:173)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.<init>(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshot.java:70)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.createSnapshot(SerializedFlowExecutionSnapshotFactory.java:70)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.snapshot.AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.snapshot(AbstractSnapshottingFlowExecutionRepository.java:75)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.putFlowExecution(DefaultFlowExecutionRepository.java:126)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:145)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:238)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    com.jeveris.web.core.filter.log.PerformanceLogFilter.doFilter(PerformanceLogFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    com.axa.ca.caem.credentials.IamAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(IamAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
```

Comment: Is there any other error in your log? `make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable` what object do you have in flow/flash scope? Have you checked all of them (all the beans and everything in parent-flow.xml)? Use transient if you don't want/need to serialize something.

Comment: Why don't you ask about the error you get when upgrading? And the error you get is NOT primefaces related, not even jsf.

Comment: Is the error upgrading like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364383/dynamic-pmenu-works-in-primefaces-3-5-not-in-4-0)?

Comment: The error is not update, I don't think it's primefaces.
I have serialized all the classes in the project. Even to test, I have also serialized the filters we have.

Comment: Is there a way to capture which class or classes are causing the failure?

Comment: `root cause ... org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy` I get an error like yours when an error (Timeout or other) occurs calling a ws with cxf. Try also to look at [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11575), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577170/spring-webflow-serialization-trouble-in-production)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. We had to go all the way down through all the classes used in the call.
There is a query that is made to BBDD using JdbcTemplate and this variable was not excluded from serialization and did not like it. It has been indicated as **transient** and fixed the problem.
Thank you